# Laravel relations doesn't return anything

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i have problem in laravel eloquent relationships.
there is 2 model in my application: article and category.

article model:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}
```

category model:

```
public function article()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
}
```

the relation between this tow is `hasMany (Category -> article)` & `belongsToMany (Article -> category)`.

category will fetch by requested slug using this method at categoryController:

```
$category = Category::where('slug', '=', $slug)->get();
```

problem will be shown in view when i want to fetch articles from category and nothhing will return back:

```
@foreach ($category->article->all() as $article)
    {{ $article->name }}
@endforeach
```

and from `@dd($category->article)` we will get empty collection:

```
Collection {#323 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your models as well ?

Comment: Article model:
`
public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }
`
Category model:
`
 public function article()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
    }
`

Comment: `belongsToMany` implies a pivot table, so both relationships would be `belongsToMany` not only 1 of them.   ... show the relationship definition for both models

Comment: @Ar.Bazargani Please don't add code as a comment, edit your question and add it there.

Comment: $category = Category::where('slug', '=', $slug)->get(); This will return a collection. 
You should use first() instead of get()

Comment: so you have a pivot table and you have foreign keys on `categories` or `articles` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @lagbox tried to highlight in a comment, for pivot tables, both relationships should be `belongsToMany`. Inverse of `hasMany` is `belongsTo`.

If one article belongs to many categories, and one category can have many articles, then, ideally, there it should be a `many-to-many` relationship. Category model should have a `belongsToMany` relationship with Article model and vice versa. Additionally, there should be a pivot table, `article_category`. And as many have suggested, you can get articles the belongs to a category by using `@foreach($category->articles as $articles)`

You can read more about many to many here: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: thanks to you, lagbox and @yasin-patel, problem solved.
two problem was there, including incorrect relationship and query.
thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @forelse blade directive like

```
@forelse ($category->article as $article)
    <li>{{ $article->name }}</li>
@empty
    <p>No articles</p>
@endforelse
```

You can check that [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#loops)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to write `$category->article->all()` . `$category->article` itself will return all articles. 
So just use like,

```
@foreach ($category->article->all() as $article)
  {{ $article->name }}
@endforeach
```

For eager loading articles, you can use 
 **`with`** keyword

```
$category = Category::with('article')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->get();
```